# White Background overlay view on Keyboard hide on Android

Tags: android, ionic-framework, keyboard

I am testing my app on Android. When an input field selected and ion-select selected key leaves an overlay, a white background is shown after the keyboard closes. The recorded video link is below:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/48FRD.jpg

code : https://github.com/Shamran-Gouse/demoapp

I have tried `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"` but then I cant see below form, I also tried the Ionic Keyboard plugin

It shouldn't happen

Comment: Could you please be more specific regarding the part of the code we should look at?

Comment: there is no errors in code, if you can see the video link white overlay is the problem